# How to unpack dict into object after self.dict(by_alias=True) in pydantic-based model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a simple pydantic-based model

```
class ClassWithId(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = Field(None, alias='_id')
```

Then I have a method

```
def to_dict(self):
    data = self.dict(by_alias=True)
    return data
```

So "id" field from the object will be mapped into `_id` field of the dictionary and it works fine.

Question is - how to do unpacking back? I mean `ClassWithId(**dict)` to map field `_id` from the dict into `id` of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to allow your model to populate by field alias via [Model Config](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/#options):

```py
class ClassWithId(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        """Specific model configurations"""
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

    id: Optional[str] = Field(None, alias='_id')
```

Now you can go back and forth between dict and object:

```py
my_obj = ClassWithId(id="abc")
my_dict = my_obj.dict(by_alias=True)

# Create a new object
my_obj_new = ClassWithId(**my_dict)
my_obj_new_2 = ClassWithId.parse_obj(my_dict)

# Make sure they're all equal
assert my_obj == my_obj_new == my_obj_new_2
```

I personally like the [`Model.parse_obj()` function](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#helper-functions) more than dynamically unpacking values. But the results should be equal.